# Python Two Dictionaries within another Dictionary within another Dictionary

Tags: python, object, copy, shared, deep-copy

I'm trying to create a structure that would lend itself nicely to parse log files. I first tried setting up dictionaries as class objects, but that doesn't work since I made them class attributes.

I'm now trying the following to set up my structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        __tBin = {'80':0, '70':0, '60':0, '50':0,'40':0}
        __pBin = {}
        __results = list()
        info = {'tBin'   : __tBin.copy(),
                'pBin'   : __pBin.copy(),
                'results': __results}

        self.writeBuffer = list()
        self.errorBuffer = list()

        self.__tests = {'test1' : info.copy(),
                        'test2' : info.copy(),
                        'test3' : info.copy()}

    def test(self):
        self.__tests['test1']['tBin']['80'] += 1
        self.__tests['test2']['tBin']['80'] += 1
        self.__tests['test3']['tBin']['80'] += 1
        print "test1: " + str(self.__tests['test1']['tBin']['80'])
        print "test2: " + str(self.__tests['test2']['tBin']['80'])
        print "test3: " + str(self.__tests['test3']['tBin']['80'])

Test().test()
```

My aim here is to create two dictionary objects (__tBin and __pBin) and making copies of them for each test (i.e. test1 test2 test3...). However, I am experiencing that test1, test2, and test3 still share the same value when I feel like I'm explicitly making copies of them. The above code also includes how I'm testing what I'm trying to accomplish.

While I expect to see 1, 1, 1 printed, I see 3, 3, 3 and I can't figure out why, especially when I explicitly do a 'copy()' on the dictionaries.

I'm on Python 2.7.4

Comment: If you're parsing xml or html, I would recommend lxml and etree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nested data structures you need to make a deep copy instead of a shallow copy.
See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Import the module `copy` at the beginning of your file. Then replace calls like `info.copy()` with `copy.deepcopy(info)`. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import copy

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        info = {'tBin'   : __tBin.copy(),
                'pBin'   : __pBin.copy(),
                'results': __results}
        ...
        self.__tests = {'test1' : copy.deepcopy(info),
                        'test2' : copy.deepcopy(info),
                        'test3' : copy.deepcopy(info)}

    def test(self):
        ...

...
```

Comment: I see, thanks. So the reason we don't need a deep copy when populating the info dict is because __tBin or __pBin don't contain more objects whereas the info dict does and therefore we need to do the recursive copy, right?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind, however, that a simple deep copy isn't always what you want. For example, if you have instance variables inside an object that point to an object that shouldn't be copied, you don't want to recursively copy them. The link I provided provides additional information that may prove useful for a deeper understanding of the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
self.__tests = {'test1' : info.copy(),
                    'test2' : info.copy(),
                    'test3' : info.copy()}
```

the variable `info` is only copied by a shallow (ie non recursive) copy. You should use `copy.deepcopy` here if you want `__tBin` and friends to be copied.